# Diagonal Difference Problem Solving HackerRank in Swift - Why is it not working?

Tags: swift

I'm doing a challenge on hacker rank and wondering why I get a runtime error, or even a wrong answer. The problem is:

> Given a square matrix, calculate the absolute difference between the sums of its diagonals.
>
> Example: 
>   
>   `3
>   11 2 4
>   4 5 6
>   10 8 -12`
>
> output: 15
>
> (The first line contains a single integer, the number of rows and columns in the matrix arr).

Here is my code:

```
func diagonalDifference(arr: [[Int]]) -> Int {
    let n = arr[0][0]
    var diagonal1 = 0
    var diagonal2 = 0
    for index in 1...n {
        diagonal1 += arr[index][index - 1]
        diagonal2 += arr[index][n - index]
    }
    return abs(diagonal1 - diagonal2)
}
```

I can't seem to find why it doesn't work.

Comment: What the content of `arr`? At which `index` and at which line do you get the error?

Comment: Show your error log when you have runtime error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issues with how the input is supposed to come in but this solution works.

```
func diagonalDifference(arr: [[Int]]) -> Int {
 var n =  arr.count
 var primaryDiagonalSum = 0
 var secondaryDiagonalSum = 0

     for index in 0..<n {
primaryDiagonalSum   +=  arr[index][index]
secondaryDiagonalSum +=  arr[index][n-index-1]
                         }  
 
    let difference = abs(primaryDiagonalSum - secondaryDiagonalSum)
    return difference
                                              }
```

Comment: tried the solution in the xcode playground seems like it will throw Index out of bounds. below is the whole code

Comment: let arr = [
 [3],
 [11 ,2 ,4],
 [4, 5 , 6],
 [10, 8, -12]
]

func diagonalDifference(arr: [[Int]]) -> Int {
    var n =  arr.count
    var primaryDiagonalSum = 0
    var secondaryDiagonalSum = 0
    
    for index in 0..<n {
        primaryDiagonalSum   +=  arr[index][index]
        secondaryDiagonalSum +=  arr[index][n-index-1]
    }
    
    let difference = abs(primaryDiagonalSum - secondaryDiagonalSum)
    return difference
}

print(diagonalDifference(arr: arr))

Answer (score 0):

```
var rsum = 0 //right diagonal sum
var lsum = 0 // left diagonal sum
var j = 0 // index to start from start for right diagonal sum
var k = arr.count-1 // index to start from end for left diagonal sum
for i in 0...k { //looping from first index to last index
    rsum += arr[i][j] //right diagonal sum
    lsum += arr[i][k] //left diagonal sum
    j += 1
    k -= 1
}
return abs(lsum - rsum)
```